# Two similar SQLite case statements, one works, the other does not

Tags: javascript, sqlite, case

The first statement works, the second comes back with the error below. The strange thing is except for variable names, they are the same statement, so if one works, the other should work as well.

```
"Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: RAF60"
```

Where RAF60 is my data. I thought that I may have a quote in the wrong place as it's trying to read my data as a column but can't see it, also looked for somewhere I may have swapped my data with an expression, but could not see that either.

The RFID1,2,3 and the CarPlates1,2,3 are formatted as text

Statement one exactly as it appears below.

```
msg.topic = 'SELECT "RFID1", "RFID2", "RFID3", case when "RFID1" = ' + readrfid + ' then RFID1 when "RFID2" = ' + readrfid + ' then RFID2 when "RFID3" = ' + readrfid + ' then RFID3  else null end dbrfid FROM SiteDB'
```

The output below from Node-Red, I reformatted it to make it easily readable. It shows that the data is populating the right fields and this code works. Its the above statement with the data inserted, just prior to being sent to SQLite

topic:

```
"SELECT "RFID1", "RFID2", "RFID3", case 
when "RFID1" = 149544749819338 then RFID1 
when "RFID2" = 149544749819338 then RFID2 
when "RFID3" = 149544749819338 then RFID3 
else null 
end dbrfid FROM SiteDB"

payload: "149544749819338"    

_msgid: "232263a1.02d34c"

_event: "node:ad044b82.8c419

0: object
```

Statement two, the sql query exactly as it appears below

```
msg.topic = 'SELECT "CarPlate1", "CarPlate2", "CarPlate3", "dbcarplate", case when "CarPlate1" = ' + readlpr + ' then CarPlate1 when "CarPlate2" = ' + readlpr + ' then CarPlate2 when "CarPlate3" = ' + readlpr + ' then CarPlate3  else null end dbcarplate FROM SiteDB
```

The output below from Node-Red, I reformatted it to make it easily readable. It also shows that the data is populating the right fields, but comes back with an error message, the statement below is the data just before its sent to SQLite

```
topic: "SELECT "CarPlate1", "CarPlate2", "CarPlate3", "dbcarplate", case 
when "CarPlate1" = RAF60 then CarPlate1 
when "CarPlate2" = RAF60 then CarPlate2 
when "CarPlate3" = RAF60 then CarPlate3 
else null 
end dbcarplate FROM SiteDB"

payload: " RAF60 "            

_msgid: "f2831f05.42c24"

_event: "node:61abb27f.bc684c"
```

It does not run in SQLite, and I get the error message.

```
"Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: RAF60"
```

Comment: Since RAF60 is a string literal in this sentence `when "CarPlate1" = RAF60 then CarPlate1 ` it needs quotes, no? (The other works because it's numeric?)

Comment: Could give that a try when I get back to work, but the way I see it is that the RAF60 is coming from the following part of the statement        ' + readlpr + '     if I put that in quotes, then it will not read the value of the variable, but do a search for      'readlpr'      which will not match any records in the database.